# How to update classNames in React properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

On scroll down I have added and removed certain classes. I want to revert the classes back on scroll up. How can it be done using only ReactJS?

I have used the event listener to change the class.

The main concept is the content of the navbar should be displayed in the center, when we scroll down the website name which is displayed in a div should be displayed on the navbar and the content which is placed in the middle, should shift to the left and the div which displays the website name should disappear. 
And when we scroll back up to the div with the website name, everything should come back to the same as it was before scrolling down.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../Styles/Navbar.css';

export class Navbar extends Component {

  handleScrollToElement(event) {
    let linkPosition = document.querySelector('.collapse');
    let brandName = document.querySelector('.navbar-brand');
    if (window.pageYOffset > 250){
      linkPosition.classList.remove('justify-content-center');
      linkPosition.classList.add('justify-content-end');
      brandName.classList.remove('invisible');
      brandName.classList.add('visible');
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollToElement);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollToElement);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top'>
          <a className='navbar-brand invisible' href='#'>Website Name</a>
          <button className='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
            <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
          </button>
          <div className='collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
            <ul className='navbar-nav'>
              <li className='nav-item active'>
                <a className='nav-link' href='#'>Home</a>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <a className='nav-link' href='#'>Item 2</a>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <a className='nav-link' href='#'>About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <a className='nav-link' href='#'>Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div className='container-fluid hpage'>
          <div className='inner'>
            <h1 className='htext' >WEBSITE TITLE</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default  Navbar;
```

Comment: Is it possible to also post a working snipped that can be run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use React.js, you should avoid direct DOM manipulation as much as possible. If you really need a reference to a DOM, you should use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead.

I would set `classNames` for `linkPosition` and `brandName` as state in `constructor` and update them in `handleScrollToElement`.

Whenever those `state` variables are changed, the `render` function will be called and will update the view.

Since `scroll` event fires a lot in short amount of time, I was worried about the performance issue as well. So I added [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in the code to prevent re-rendering the unchanged view.

You can also consider to debounce the scroll event handler function to be called to reduce the amount of calling the `setState`.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../Styles/Navbar.css';

export class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      linkPositionClassName: 'justify-content-center',
      brandNameClassName: 'invisible',
    };
  }

  handleScrollToElement(event) {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 250){
      this.setState({
        linkPositionClassName: 'justify-content-end',
        brandNameClassName: 'visible',
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        linkPositionClassName: 'justify-content-center',
        brandNameClassName: 'invisible',
      });
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { linkPositionClassName, brandNameClassName } = this.state;

    // component needs to re-render only when at least one of the state changes
    return nextState.linkPositionClassName !== linkPositionClassName || nextState.brandNameClassName !== brandNameClassName;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollToElement);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollToElement);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top'>
          <a className=`navbar-brand ${this.state.brandNameClassName}` href='#'>Website Name</a>
          <button className='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
            <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
          </button>
          <div className=`collapse navbar-collapse ${this.state.linkPositionClassName}` id='navbarSupportedContent'>
            <ul className='navbar-nav'>
              <li className='nav-item active'>
                <a className='nav-link' href='#'>Home</a>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <a className='nav-link' href='#'>Item 2</a>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <a className='nav-link' href='#'>About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <a className='nav-link' href='#'>Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div className='container-fluid hpage'>
          <div className='inner'>
            <h1 className='htext' >WEBSITE TITLE</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Thank You. One problem the content before scroll in the navbar isn't centered properly, any css can be added?

Comment: default `linkPositionClassName` is the one with center. You may want to look at the css for the classname.